# adobe acrobat reader - how to save your place?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I'm trying to read an ebook in adobe acrobat reader and I want to save the position I'm at between computer reboots / closing reader.

How can I save the page I'm at, or even better auto save?

Is there a better program out there that I can use? Is it possible to set my own bookmarks with Acrobat Reader?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From Adobe Acrobat Reader:

`Edit -> Preferences -> Documents`

[x] Restore last view settings when reopening documents

This will save your last page per pdf.

Comment: `For Adobe Acrobat Professional 6. Edit -> Preferences -> Startup then select All Documents from "Reopen Documents to Last viewed page" drop down.` - comment by Anon. User

Comment: You should be granted a prize or something !

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this feature does not work in Adobe Reader X version 10.1.3. It used to work before. Maybe this is a regression or just another Windows 7 64 bit problem. I applied the latest Adobe updates, still no luck. Is there anyone else with this problem in Adobe Reader X?

EDIT1: 
I found a work around for anyone else who runs in to a similar issue. Use Adobe Digital Editions to read the PDF. That automatically saves the last page and the document is a lot more readable.

This could be a deliberate attempt from Adobe to push us to using the Digital Editions, to enlarge the platform and maybe, to capture some valuable user information as well.

EDIT2: Adobe Reader fails to save the place for some pdfs and works for others. My previous pdf was more than 10mb, so size may have something to do with it. This is probably a bug in Adobe Reader 10.1.3

Comment: For some reason, the original downloaded copies of many PDF files still won't automtically reopen at their last viewing position with Adobe Reader X and this, even with the 'Restore last view settings when reopening documents' checked.

What I have to do is to re-save them from Adobe Reader  (File -> Save As).  The saved copy will then automatically reopen to its last viewed position.  Quite useful when you are reading a book a few hundreds pages long.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior for Adobe Reader DC as @SylvainL reported.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a complete answer yet. I'm using Acrobat Reader DC, and the given answer works -- for a couple of weeks, anyway. I've discovered that if I don't continue reading the pdf fairly soon, it no longer opens where I left off. Today I saw a suggestion I'm trying. Apparently you can place a "sticky note" in the text. I tried it with a book I will probably set aside and then pick up again several weeks later (Shirer's Berlin Diary). All I put on the note was "bkmk," for "bookmark".

Comment: This would work but how do you find the sticky note afterwards?  Would this work across multiple devices?

Comment: You can search for it, so write something like "bookmark" on the note. I'm not satisfied with this and I haven't really tried it over an extended time, but there simply doesn't seem to be a solution. I guess Adobe figures they don't want to make their free product too satisfactory.